# Hello World externalTerminal Issue On Chromebook

Tags: c#, linux, chromebook, crosh

I trying to run a hello world program on Visual Studio Code in C# on my Chromebook in order to make sure that everything is set up correctly, but every time i try to run it opens to a terminal that says "chronos@localhost". I am entirely new to programming so any help is very much appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

I removed and reinstalled it and that did not make any difference. I searched online anywhere I could but couldn't find anything helpful.

Again, i'm new and stupid so any suggestions are really appreciated!

[Requested Program.cs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOLkh.png)

Comment: _Visual Studio Code_ is not Visual Studio. Please edit your question.

Comment: The "`chronos@localhost`" text is just [the default bash prompt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bash/Prompt_customization): it's your login username followed by your machine's network-name - it's because (historically) terminal-users would often be connected to dozens of remote *nix machines simultaneously so it helps to be able to instantly tell which remote session and machine you're in.

Comment: Show us your `Program.cs` file.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto I uninstalled and reinstalled according the instructions in your tutorial and am still having this issue.

Comment: @Popha If possible, remove Linux and turn on.

Comment: @Dai Is the screenshot that I added helpful at all?

Comment: @NorioYamamoto I removed and then reinstated Linux, and it did not seem to make a difference.